# Adding a specific line to a scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, frequency

I have a plot of spectra vs frequency and I am trying to add a specific line through the data and what I have right now is

```
plot(freq, spc, log='xy', type='l')
y.loess <- loess(spc ~ freq, span=0.8, data.frame(x=freq, y=spc))
y.predict <- predict(y.loess, data.frame(x=freq))
lines(freq,y.predict)
lines(freq,y.predict, col='red')
```

This gives me the following 
[image]

The black part of the graph is correct and what I need but the red line is incorrect what I need should look something like

[image]

I thought loess would work but it's not quite what I am going for.  How do I add a line to my data to make it look like the second picture?

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question but rather a statistical one. Are you asking how to fit the points to a suitable model?

Comment: Your `span=` might be too small, causing the sudden downward variation in the red line when a handful of outlier cases come into the calculation.

Comment: I think fitting a model is what I want to do.  I am just unsure how to do it.  If this question is more appropriate as a statistics question I will ask it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *pre-scale* the values and try a kernel smoother:

```
Ks <- ksmooth(log(freq),log(spc),kernel = "normal",bandwidth=0.3)  
lines(Ks,col="red")
```

You can play around with the bandwidth or base it on standard deviation of your log(data). Look at this [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression) for alternative using npreg.

Comment: This gets rid of the large drop in my line.  I ended up using the binAverage function but the ksmooth does what I need as well.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a reproducible example, so, I'll be very simplistic in my answer. You can try out the existing function  `scatter.smooth`:

```
require(graphics)

with(cars, scatter.smooth(speed, dist))

## You can elaborate more on the line and dots as your will:
with(cars, scatter.smooth(speed, dist, lpars =
                    list(col = "red", lwd = 3, lty = 3)))
```